# Can clang be told not to analyze certain files?

Tags: xcode, profiling, clang

I'm trying to use clang to profile a project I'm working on. The project includes a rather large static library that is included in Xcode as a dependency.

I would really like clang to not analyze the dependencies' files, as it seems to make clang fail. Is this possible? I've been reading the clang documentation, and I haven't found it.

Comment: Apple has a decent forum for confidential discussions of products released under NDA at http://devforums.apple.com in which questions like this can be answered by Apple folk and other disclosed developers.

Comment: (unless you're asking about using the scan-build tool at http://clang.llvm.org/StaticAnalysis.html, which is indeed public. In that case, just list the source files you want to analyze, as shown in Basic Usage on that page.)

Comment: I'm just talking about the scan-build tool. Unfortunately, under the basic usage, it doesn't have anything about excluding files from analysis. If you're using scan-build on a project, it by default analyzes all of the files within that project, including my massive static library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, this isn't really an answer, but it worked well enough.

What I ended up doing was building the static library ahead of time, and then building the project using scan-build. Since there was already an up-to-date build of the static library, it wasn't rebuilt and thus wasn't scanned.

I'd still love to have a real answer for this, though.

Answer (score 15):

As a last resort, there is a brute force option.

Add this to the beginning of a file:

```
// Omit from static analysis.
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
```

Add this to the end:

```
#endif // not __clang_analyzer__
```

and clang --analyze won't see the contents of the file.

reference: [Controlling Static Analyzer Diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-static-analyzer-diagnostics)

Comment: This implies that I have to set this macro on every source file in the static library, doesn't it? That's not manageable IMO. I don't won't to modify my dependencies at all, since I'm using CocoaPods for my iOS projects.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, in 2018 the option was implemented.

Use `--exclude <path>` [[1]](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22594) [[2]](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52153) option

> --exclude
>
> Do not run static analyzer against files found in this    directory
>   (You can specify this option multiple times).    Could be useful when
>   project contains 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Is there a way to use this option with `clang++`? I tried `-Xanalyzer --exclude`, but it tells me `error: unknown argument: '--exclude'`

Answer (score 3):

I don't use XCode, but using scan-build in linux the following works for me. I my case, I want to run the static analysis on all first party, non-generated code. However, I want to avoid running it on third_party code and generated code.

On the command line, clang-analyzer is hooked into the build when scan-build sets CC and CXX environment variables to ccc-analyzer and c++-analyzer locations. I wrote two simple scripts called ccc-analyzer.py and c++-analyzer.py and hooked them in to the compile in place of the default. In these wrapper scripts, I simply looked at the path of the file being compiled and then run either the raw compiler directly (if I wish to avoid static analysis) or the c*-analyzer (if I wish for static analysis to occur). My script is in python and tied to my specific build system, but as an example that needs modification:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def main(argv):
  is_third_party_code = False
  for i in range(len(argv)):
    arg = argv[i]
    if arg == '-c':
      file_to_compile = argv[i + 1]
      if '/third_party/' in file_to_compile or \
            file_to_compile.startswith('gen/'):
        is_third_party_code = True
      break
  if is_third_party_code:
    argv[0] = '/samegoal/bin/clang++'
  else:
    argv[0] = '/samegoal/scan-build/c++-analyzer'
  return subprocess.call(argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Cool, this seems like it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode users, you can exclude individual files from static analyzer by adding the following flags in the Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources section: `-Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks`